# Android download image and show in ImageView with black shadow

Tags: android

I want to download an image from my server from my android app and show it in an `ImageView` with a black layer on top with a certain amount of opacity.

I was able to do this on an iPhone very easily using a `UIView` with `blackColor` as background color and just placing it above a `UIImageView` with the alpha set at .4. Is there a similar way to do this on Android? I have been reading quite a bit on this, most of the approaches online say to use selectors, etc.

But this wont work when the image is downloaded from the server and then putting black view on top.

Comment: Will the image always be the same size?

Comment: Yes, always same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could very much benefit from the usage of a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

As a summary, a FrameLayout is, well, a singular frame where everything put into it is essentially stacked *in front of each other* (as opposed to a LinearLayout where things are stacked on top of each other).

An example of the way you would set this up would be as follows:

```
<!-- This can be whatever your parent view is -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Here is the actual usage of the FrameLayout.  Replace the height -->
    <!-- and width with the size of the image that you're using           -->
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp">

        <!-- You won't use the src tag seeing as you get your image from a -->
        <!-- server, but I have it for the sake of demonstration.          -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/your_image_view"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <!-- This is a basic view that has a black background and a .4 alpha -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:alpha=".4"
            android:background="#000000"/>


    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Thumbs up with a shadow cover]

For your own purposes, you may need to play around a bit with the height and width attributes, but otherwise this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an a bitmap and set it to imageview:

```
class myClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadHomeImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;

    }

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap icon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return icon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null)
        {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to have the black view on top of it with opacity. I have no problem downloading the image.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing it in Android:

**A. The old way:**

Download an image:

```
Bitmap downloadByUrl(String url) {
     // initilize the default HTTP client object
     DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     if (entity != null) {
             InputStream inputStream = null;
             inputStream = entity.getContent();
             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
             inputStream.close();
     }
}
```

And load into ImageView:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

It's a *very* good idea to place the loading code in a separate thread, e.g. by using AsyncTask, making your code something like:

```
new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>() {
       @Override protected Result doInBackground() {
           // executed on worker thread
           bmp = downloadByUrl(String url)
       }

       @Override protected void onPostExecute() {
           // executed on UI thread
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
       }
}.execute(params);
```

**B. The new way:**

use [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) that will do much of the work for you, and will probably do it smarter than most of us:

Declare a NetworkImageView rather than a standard ImageView:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_placeholder" />
```

.. And assign a loader e.g. at onCreate():

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getImageLoader(); 
imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) instead of Volley and enjoy similar results.

In both cases you will need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have no problem using Volley and downloading the image. My question was how do I out a black view on top?